# MySQL INTO OUTFILE errors?

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

Just was wondering when using this with MySQL does it produce any errors like if there wasn't enough space to place the file on the server or it was denied permission etc? Did a Google but couldn't find much.

Comment: I assume it  will. Why not try out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' form of SELECT writes the selected rows to a file. The file is created on the server host, so you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. file_name cannot be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as /etc/passwd and database tables from being destroyed.

Of course if there's no space MySQL will give you an error as well.